# Map an arbitrary value from an array to a color that exists in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, spectrum

I want to map an arbitrary value to a color scale, for use in a heat map.

I already have the ability to generate a color spectrum between 2 extreme colors as an array, like this:

```
create_color_spectrum("#b33939", "#ff5252", 20)
```

...which gives outputs like this:

```
["#fb5050", "#f74f4f", "#f34e4e", "#ef4d4d", "#ec4b4b", "#e84a4a", "#e44949", "#e04848", "#dc4646", "#d94545", "#d54444", "#d14343", "#cd4141", "#c94040", "#c63f3f", "#c23e3e", "#be3c3c", "#ba3b3b", "#b63a3a", "#b23838"]
```

Now say I have another array of values (*values array*) like this (same length as the *colors array*):

```
[0.020565500406834823, 0.0006918573709419904, 0.03614457831325302, 0.014884840151254727, 0.9638554216867471, 0.005208333333333333, 0.0006248326341158618, 0.14285714285714285, 0.004872900466547537, 0.8571428571428577, 0, 0.2142857142857144, 0, 0.2499999999999991, 0.5000000004656613, 0.45534591194968543, 0.6349489795918367, 0.25, 0.15218156916454706, 0]
```

How can I extract an appropriate color from the *colors array* for each value in the *values array*? The idea is that smaller values are towards the beginning of the *colors array*, and larger values are towards the end of the *colors array*.

I need to read in a value from the *values array* and map it to an index in the *colors array*.

I could attempt to rescale the values array, but this wouldn't produce distinct integer values, which would be needed to index the *colors array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I build an array of small objects to contain the value and the original index in the values array.  Then I sort the new array by value, assign a color to each element by its new index, and re-sort it by original index.

```js
const colors = ["#fb5050", "#f74f4f", "#f34e4e", "#ef4d4d", "#ec4b4b", "#e84a4a", "#e44949", "#e04848", "#dc4646", "#d94545", "#d54444", "#d14343", "#cd4141", "#c94040", "#c63f3f", "#c23e3e", "#be3c3c", "#ba3b3b", "#b63a3a", "#b23838"];

const values = [0.020565500406834823, 0.0006918573709419904, 0.03614457831325302, 0.014884840151254727, 0.9638554216867471, 0.005208333333333333, 0.0006248326341158618, 0.14285714285714285, 0.004872900466547537, 0.8571428571428577, 0, 0.2142857142857144, 0, 0.2499999999999991, 0.5000000004656613, 0.45534591194968543, 0.6349489795918367, 0.25, 0.15218156916454706, 0];

// keep track of the old index and sort by value
const valueMap = values.map((val, i) => ({oldIndex: i, value: val})).sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value);

// add the appropriate color to each element of the sorted array
valueMap.forEach((val, i) => val.color = colors[i]);
//check this console.log to verify it sorted/assigned properly
//console.log(JSON.stringify(valueMap));

// resort it by oldIndex
valueMap.sort((a,b) => a.oldIndex - b.oldIndex);

// get just the array of colors
const newColors = valueMap.map(val => val.color);
console.log(newColors);
```

Comment: The colors don't appear to scale from min to max: https://codepen.io/cybertime/pen/xxEZPOO?editors=0010

Comment: The colors don't scale at all.  I merely sort the values and assign a color from the colors array based on the new index, such that smaller values are toward the beginning of the colors array, and larger values are toward the end.  That's what you wanted, right?

Comment: However the code in your codepen does exactly what I expect, what problem are you seeing?

Comment: Never mind, this is correct, my apologies. Great work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map each of your values to an index in your colour map. To do this, you need to know the minimum value you expect to see (that looks like `0` in your example), the maximum value you expect to see (I'm guessing `1`) and the number of colours available (`20` here).

```js
// You can hard code these if you know them and want a constant representation
// The lowest possible value
const valueFloor = Math.min(...values);
// The range between the lowest and highest possible value
const valueRange = Math.max(...values) - valueFloor;

const maxColorIdx = colors.length - 1;

for (const value of values) {
    // Normalize your value to something between 0 and 1
    const normalizedValue = (value - valueFloor) / valueRange;
    // Scale your normalized value to an integerrepresenting a color index 
    const colorIdx = Math.round(normalizedValue * maxColorIdx);
    console.debug(colors[colorIdx]);
}
```

This will print out the "heatmap" colour for each of your values.

Comment: Seems to produce empty colors: https://codepen.io/cybertime/pen/MWjKRYy?editors=0010

Comment: @Cybernetic you missed out the `...` spread operators on the `Math.min` and `Math.max` calls.

Comment: Ahh my bad. ES6. Thank you.